# Portable scripting language for deployment?

Tags: deployment, groovy

We have set of unix shell(ksh) scripts used for deployment of our product.
Actually there is a mixture of ksh+sed+awk+ant code.
Our product works on AIX only so we did not try to do our scripts portable.
But now we need to run part of our scripts not only on AIX but on Windows also.
We need to have ability to create/update DB both from AIX and from Windows.
Now for this part of functionality we use ksh+ant.

We have a requirement to install as few as possible tools on this Windows box.
In the best case it should be JRE+our products only.
What do you propose to use instead of ksh?
As I know we can put Groovy jar into our project and write this part of functionality on Groovy.
In this case this code will be portable.
May be there are better solutions than Groovy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any JVM language such as Jython or Scala should work as well as Groovy so it’s really a choice of what the developers are comfortable with. I’ve had good success with Groovy and have been able to bundle Groovy as a jar file and execute any script I wanted in the following way

```
Java -jar groovy.jar myscript.groovy
```

I’ve been able to do this on z/OS, Windows, and Linux.